# How to correctly combine equally weighted predictions and results with uncertainty

Tags: regression, logistic, ordinal-data, ensemble-learning

I understand there have been a lot of answers on combining predictions, but I cannot seem to find anything that answers all of my questions.

I have 5 regions of the heart to test, and each region can be described on a 1-5 scale (normal = 1 abnormal = 5). Each test I apply tells me, with around 70% \pm 40% confidence (each region is different so these numbers vary a fair bit) whether the particular region is either a 1, 2, 3, 4 or 5.

How do I combine these predictions to get a confidence of the health of the heart as a whole if:

a) all the regions return the same result ( 5 tests each with a confidence of ~ 70%, all indicating the heart is a healthy 1)

b) The regions return 2 or more integers (Here i would expect to be able to say that I have a confidence of >70% that the heart is at 1.5, if the two integers returned were 1 and two.

any help, or redirection to other reading would be greatly appreciated! I'll be on all day trying to figure this out, so if something isn't clear, please leave a comment and I'll respond promptly!

Thanks.

Comment: Is this a problem of time series analysis or is the word "forecast" being misused here? What are these "forecasts" you're mentioning and how are they measured? Also, what are these "tests" and these percentages mentioned? Hypothesis tests? Confidence levels? Please, explain better.

Comment: In the same way you would forecast a 70% chance of rain, I'm essentially forecasting a 70% certainty that a region is malfunctioning

Comment: It sounds to me that your predictions were derived from a cross-sectional regression model, not a time series model, therefore the terms "forecast" and "forecast-combination" are very much misleading.

Comment: Sorry, I've not quite got the nomenclature down with all of this. I think you are right, so thank you for the correction! Do you have any idea as to how I should combine the stats?

Comment: That's ok, I have edited your post.

Comment: Anyone had any thoughts on this?

Answer (score 1):

Some initial comments: How to combine them seems to depend on the use you want to make of this knowledge. This is essential even before trying to find a combined probability. Consider an example different from yours but with the same abstract problem: we know the health conditions of a person's organs and would like to say something about the health condition of the person as a whole. Suppose this person has a liver in very bad condition but a healthy heart (unlikely, but anyway...). Would you say that the person as a whole is healthy? They probably need treatment – they could die because of their liver, even if the heart is healthy. So here the *minimum* among the statuses of all components could be taken as an indication of the global health. In other situations an average may be more appropriate. Also, is any of the regions more important than the others for the global functioning of the heart?

More formally:

If I understood correctly you want (1) to describe the global health condition by a single number, and (2) to assign a probability to this number. Then I see it this way:

1) The global state of the heart is at first given by a 5-tuple of quantities, each of which can assume five values. That is, your "sample space" is $\{1,\dotsc,5\}^5$. I'd start by writing down a multivariate probability distribution for this 5-tuple. And the question is:

– Are the probabilities of the five quantities independent? In this case the joint probability is just their product.

– Are they not independent? In this case you'd need to find a joint probability that correctly marginalizes to the five marginals. You could check maximum-entropy methods to do this, or assume some other model.

2) Once you have this joint probability, you must find a way to get a single number from the 5-tuple. There are again various ways to do this, eg:
the minimum, the maximum, the average, a weighted average, etc. Each of these defines a function from the space of 5-tuples, $\{1,\dotsc,5\}^5$, to the space $\{1,\dotsc,5\}$. Once you have decided upon the right function, you can find the probability for this number by the usual probability-mapping formulae between different sample spaces.

Sorry for the vagueness of this comment, it seems the answer depends a lot on the context.

Comment: Thank you for the detail in your response!
More info: The regions are assumed to have equal weighting, and it is the health of the heart, not the patient being described. I am not looking for a link to the patients global health (that was my poor choice of words), more the patients cardiac health. 

I have the probability for each number (acquired from machine learning in Python). Knowing that these 5 probabilities related to 5 integers all describe the same object, i.e:

Comment: 70% \pm 40% that region 1 has a health of 1,  

65% \pm 46% that region 2 has a health of 2,  


.
.
65% \pm 40% that region 5 has a health of 1,  
It is these I am wanting to combine to get an overall forecast of the health of the heart as a whole (if they are equally weighted then the probability and descriptive integer should all be combined to point to a new probability and new integer) 

This is difficult without getting into too much depth, so forgive me if my descriptions are a little lacking !

Thanks, again

Comment: Hi Bruce, my initial example was meant to be different from your problem; I didn't explain myself well (have edited the text now).

I think I've understood the kind of data you have. I find it curious that the machine-learning algorithm gives an interval probability to a single value. For the approach I'm proposing you'd need the distribution over all five values. A fictitious example:

region 1: $P(\mathrm{health}=1) = 70\%$, $P(\mathrm{health}=2) = 10\%$, $P(\mathrm{health}=3) = 10\%$, $P(\mathrm{health}=4) = 5\%$, $P(\mathrm{health}=5) = 5\%$. And so on.

Comment: So I have the probability (or certainty) with associated uncertainties of the regions health being described by an integer (i.e the machine learning will tell me how confident it is of the result provided), and I want to combine these 5 results

Comment: I understood you! It is the persons heart health, the organ alone that I am trying to describe. This is not for treatment purposes, but more a diagnostic description. If someone has a heart attack, one region might die, and the other 4 be perfectly fine. On the scale this persons regions would look like 5,1,1,1,1. In the current system their overall health may be described as a 2 (so yes, an average seems appropriate).

Comment: My main issue is the current system is an objective one, you look at the heart and say "yeah, that's about a 2". I'm happy to describe the health of the heart as an average of the 1-5 numbers, it's the combining of the probabilities (and uncertainties) attached to this I can't seem to wrap my head around.

Comment: If you know the global health number is the average of the five, half of the problem is solved. I'm thinking of a way to use the interval probabilities you have (eg 30%–110% for the first region), instead of probability distributions over the 5 health values.

Comment: Question: does you final answer *have* to be of the form "global health condition is 2 with a probability of $x\% \pm \Delta x\%$"? This format does not seem very informative.

Comment: No, it doesn't, if you have any other suggestions I'm all ears! 
I'm designing this test for cardiac health, so as long as I can support my decisions then it's fine (such as averaging to obtain global health number). 

currently it seems to be a sensible way to report findings as I can say that the combination of tests can predict global health number with an accuracy of "x% ± Δx%". I suppose I could take the lower bound of this: e.g if i had 80%  ±  10%, I could say that it can be predicted with at least 70% certainty.

Comment: Hi Bruce, you're welcome, it's an interesting problem. From my point of view I'd prefer, for each region, a probability distribution over the five health conditions than an interval probability for the most likely condition. Let's speak of region 1 for example.I'd prefer to know

$P(h=1)=a_1, P(h=2)=a_2, \dotsc, P(h=5)=a_5$,

rather than "Most likely health condition is 2 with $x\pm\Delta x$ probability". For two reasons:

Comment: 1. If the health condition is 1 with 60%, how is the remaining 40% distributed? It could be all on condition 5 – which means that this region is either very healthy or very abnormal, and I'd be worried. Or it could be all on condition 2 – which means that this region is either very healthy or slightly less healthy, and I wouldn't worry.

2. The probability $x$ already expresses an uncertainty about a prediction. Up to now I've encountered very few situations in which the "uncertainty about the uncertainty" was of any real use...

Comment: Luckily the distribution is fairly linear, meaning that if it is not 1, it will be 2 or maybe (unlikely) 3. 
If I could get the probabilities as described, the end goal is still to combine this to create an overall cardiac health report. If I were to combine the most probable, how would this work? 

I understand the uncertainty on the uncertainty appears useless! It is useful in the sense that I am essentially being told that this machine learning script can predict the correct accuracy 70% of the time. There is naturally an uncertainty on this, which helps describe how good the data is

Comment: I would like to carry this through to show that for larger sample sizes, while the accuracy may remain, you can be more confident of it with higher sample sizes

Comment: I'm sorry, I do see how stupid that sounds. Imagine the machine is basically a really confident person who says they get things right 70% of the time and you know that it's more like 60 - 80% of the time. If they were to guess at this, they might say "well, I did 5 tests, I'm now 99% sure of this". I'd still want to know how much I can trust the guy, if it turns out he's 99% sure \pm 100%, then he's useless

Comment: Well, it isn't stupid, and in your field it may well be useful. I'm still thinking of a way of using only the max probability as in your case. I hope some help will also come from more expert people n the meantime.

Comment: Thank you for your patience and consideration! This has been a headache for me for 2 days now!

Comment: G. Bruce, please do upvote @pglpm if you find that his contribution has been helpful.

Comment: Hi @Digio - My reputation is not yet high enough to up vote, otherwise I would have done so!